# Can the complete graph $K_9$, be 2-coloured with no blue $K_4$ or red triangles?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

I am working on the following problem on 2-coloured complete graphs:

> $K_9$ is coloured red and blue and contains no red triangle and no
>   blue $K_4$ then every vertex must have red degree 3 and blue degree 5.
>   Is this possible?

I am pretty sure the answer is 'no' but I am not sure how to explain my answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @KaJhansen can you do this one?

Comment: Where does this problem comes from?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**.  There are $9$ vertices; if every one of them had "red degree" $3$, then the graph containing only the red edges would contradict one of the most basic theorems of graph theory.

Comment: Thanks, am I looking to say that this cannot happen as we would need to have an edge which goes from one vertex but does not go to another vertex? Do you know how to say what I've said in a 'mathematically correct' way?

Comment: Look up the *handshaking lemma*.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Take bicolored $K_9$.
- Observe that there exists a vertex of even blue degree and name it $u$.
- Set $B$ and $R$ to be respectively the blue and red neighbors of $u$; observe that $|B| \geq 5$ or $|R| \geq 4$.
- Strenghten that to $|B| \geq 6$ or $|R| \geq 4$.
- Bicolored $K_6$ will always have either blue or red triangle.
- Bicolored $K_4$ is either all blue or it has at least one red edge.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$